# currentIndex for pageviewcontroller is displaying incorrectly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uipageviewcontroller

Inconsistency when displaying page numbers on the navigation bar

**Issue #**

on first page it displays 0 of 20

to display 1 of 20 using

```
[self displaycurrentIndex:1];
```

in viewDidload method.

On second page shows 1 of 20, on third page it shows 2 of 20, on fourth 3 of 20 ........

and when pages are turned in reverse order it displays 0 of 20 on first page instead of 1 of 20.

**Isuue #**

As soon as when i click on page to turn it over it changes the current page number which is wrong because  it should display the next currentpage number only when next page displays not when page is about to display next page

Using instance displaycurrentIndex method to display currentpagenumber

```
- (void) displaycurrentIndex:(NSUInteger)currentIndex {

self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"Page %i of %i",
                             currentIndex,
                             CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument)];
}
```

In viewDidload method

```
 [self currentIndex:1];
```

Using pageviewcontroller datasource methods to display current page number

```
#pragma mark - UIPageViewControllerDataSource Methods

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pages" ofType:@"pdf"];

    NSURL *pdfurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfurl);

    contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];

    currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController page]];

    if (currentIndex == 0) {

        return nil;

    }

    contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex - 1];

     [self displaycurrentIndex:currentIndex - 1];

    return contentViewController;

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pages" ofType:@"pdf"];

    NSURL *pdfurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfurl);

    contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];

    currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController page]];

    if (currentIndex == totalPages - 1) {

        return nil;
    }
    contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex + 1];

    [self displaycurrentIndex:currentIndex + 1];

    return contentViewController;

}
```

How can i fix this.

Thanks for help.

Comment: pageIndex is zero based like every other index in objective-c you'll have to add one to it.

Comment: I know index always starts from zero for that i already added 1 to it. If you will check my post

Comment: Where? You mean in `[self displaycurrentIndex:1];`? This does nothing. This will set it to display 1 but then that one does not actually affect the index. You need to change your displayCurrentIndex method to use `currentIndex + 1`

Comment: yeah exactly that is what i m doing in before and after pageviewcontroller datasource methods please check it. Can you please check my edit that method is working exactly the way it should but it starts working after i turn 4 pages over

Comment: Dude, don't make it complicated. You should be doing that logic in the displayIndex function

Comment: I tried it is working. Now only issue is that why it is changing currentpagenumber as soon as i click on page to turn it over. It should change with currentpagenumber only once page is displayed.